# How to list containers and its info running a pod using kubectl command

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, rancher

When we run kubectl get pod  => it is listing the count of containers running inside a pod and restart count. So I am not sure which container gets restarted. Either I need to login to UI or using kubectl describe pods.

```
NAME       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
test-pod   2/2   Running      5         14h
```

But I need to see each container names and its restart count using kubectl command somethings as below.

```
NAME            STATUS    RESTARTS    AGE
container-1     Running      2         14h
container-2     Running      3         14h
```

It would be helpful if someone helps me on this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
kubectl get pods <pod-name> -o jsonpath='{.spec.containers[*].name} {.status.containerStatuses[*].restartCount} {.status.containerStatuses[*].state}'
```

You will get in result container-name, restartCount and state.
Then you will be able to format it in such way as you need.